# Считать пары значений в словарь

Tags: python

Добрый день, помогите, пожалуйста, с такой задачей, есть файл, где есть данные ввиде:

```
а 00000
z 00001
s 000100
g 000101
```

Сейчас я оттуда данные считываю таким образом:

```
def read_key(file_key):
with file_key as f:
    result = [map(str, line.split()) for line in f]
return result
```

Всё записывается в двумерный список, мне же нужно записать в словарь, где g - ключ, 000101 - значение, просто сам как-то не пойму=)
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def read_key(file_key):
    result = {}
    with open(file_key) as f:
       for line in f:
           key, value = line.split()
           result[key] = value
    return result
```

Comment: я так понял file_key - это имя файла?

Comment: да, это имя файла, большое спасибо.

Comment: не забывай отмечать правильный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
with open(file_name) as fp:
    result = dict(map(str.split, fp))
```